# How to use routes with the same path without affecting each other?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Current example
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-issue-xyw00

Situation: I have a existing reactjs app and I'm trying to build a website frame 'around' it.

So in the example

- Click `open layover`, the content in red is the existing app.
- Click `Layover Dashboard`, the content in the layover updates
- Click `close`
- The content in the frame has also been updated (**which is not what I want**).

But they both have a `home` and a `dashboard`.

I've searched for nested routing, but the questions are completely different from what I'm describing.

Is it possible to use multiple routes in different components with the same path without affecting each other? Or is there an alternative for my problem without changing any route to the existing app? Or is it just not possible to ignore routes?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Could you describe your desired outputs step-by-step?

Comment: I've edited the steps of my issue. I have routes with the same path and the desired output is for them to not affect each other

Comment: I think there will be some kind of inconsistence here. For example, if your `LayoverContent` changes the route to `/dashboard`, then your close the layover, what suppose to be shown, `/dashboard` route on the URL but the content of `Home` component? I don't think it's a good idea, maybe you would like to describe the UI behaviour you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, keep the home component but show the dashboard on the layover. So using the same route paths without affecting each other